# Concave extrusion of mesh

Tags: modeling, edit-mode, faces

How do you extrude the top face of an oval circle (flower petal) that it evenly bugles/concave?
I attached a picture of what I tried to model:

[image: sample of]

I used a bezier tool to form the shape of the petal and convert it to a mesh. The top face is triangular. I also tried the sculpt pull tool but it looks terrible?

[image: example of model]

Can anyone please give me advice, how to create even square polygons on the top face and extrude evenly?

Answer (score 1):

One way...

[image]

1. Create an empty circle
2. Give it a Mirror modifier with *Bisect* checked in the mirror axis. Move half the vertices toward the center, until you get the shape you like, and apply the modifier.
3. With all selected in Edit mode, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>F</kbd> Face menu > *Grid Fill.*
4. Assign a Solidify modifier
5. Assign a Bevel modifier, by angle, (Segments 2, Profile 1?) to catch the sharp edges
6. Assign a Subdivision Surface modifier

Now select the central vertex, and under <kbd>O</kbd>, proportional editing, raise it up a bit, with a diameter and falloff profile you like, to get the curve.

..and maybe, in Edit, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>V</kbd> Vertex menu, > *Smooth* the vertices, a touch

[image]

*Grid Fill* needs an even number of vertices to work cleanly, the Mirror modifier helps ensure that, even if your petal isn't quite the same shape as this one.

Comment: Thank you Robin, your answer is super cool!